# c# lambda expression with specific "where" "is null"

Tags: c#, lambda, null, where-clause

Could somebody tell me how to create a c# **lambda expression** to get the following result:

I want to get all rows with value NOT starting with a 'B'. So rows with ID 1,3,4,5 and 6 need to be in the result. INCLUDING the one with the NULL value.

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A01 |
| 2 | B01 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | A02 |
| 6 | A02 |
| 7 | B02 |

`.Where(x => !x.Value.StartsWith("B"))` is not giving the row with the NULL value

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EF or Linq ? it is string "NULL" or DbNull ?

Comment: what about naive solution like just using "value is null or starts with ..."

Comment: As @Selvin said, before asking this question, have you tried `.Where(x => x.Value == null || !x.Value.StartsWith("B"))`?

Comment: You are welcome. Also, since you are new to StackOverflow, I would like to inform you that you can upvote good answers and accept the answer that helped you the most by checking the tick mark next to the Answer. On this site an upvote or an accepted answer counts as a "thanks".

Answer (score 1):

Using [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching), you can write:

```cs
var result = list.Where(x => x.Value is not ['B', ..]);
```

The string is treated as a list of `char` and a list pattern is applied to it. This includes `null` values because the list pattern implicitly tests for `null`.

If you want to also exclude strings starting with a lower case "b", you can use the pattern `is not ['B' or 'b', ..]`.

---

Test setup in a Console app using the type:

```cs
record class Data(int ID, string Value);
```

Test:

```cs
var list = new List<Data> {
    new(1,"A01"),
    new(2,"B01"),
    new(3,null),
    new(4,""),
    new(5,"A02"),
    new(6,"A02"),
    new(7,"B02"),
    new(8,"B"),
    new(9,"D"),
};

var result = list.Where(x => x.Value is not ['B', ..]);
foreach (var item in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints:

```
Data { ID = 1, Value = A01 }
Data { ID = 3, Value =  }
Data { ID = 4, Value =  }
Data { ID = 5, Value = A02 }
Data { ID = 6, Value = A02 }
Data { ID = 9, Value = D }
```

Comment: Question, first time I am seeing something like this done. Shouldn't the where clause have `x.Value?[0]` ? I don't get how this is able to presume `.StartsWith()`

Comment: @Narish. The pattern `['B', ..]` denotes a sequence being not null (implicitly), starting with the character `'B'` (this is `Value[0]`) and possibly having more elements (expressed by `..`). And because we say `is not`, we get the inverse result. I.e., either `null` or a sequence not starting with `B` which includes an empty sequence (an empty string). See: [C# List Patterns](https://www.csharptutorial.net/csharp-tutorial/csharp-list-patterns/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Always surprises me how concise list patterns can be, while communicating so many layers of validation

Answer (score 0):

How about

`list.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) || !x.Value.StartsWith("B"));`

Comment: short version would be `list.Where(x.Value?.StartsWith("B") != false);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the direction. I found the solution by combining the answers:

```
class Program
{
    record class Data(int ID, string? Value);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        var list = new List<Data> {
            new(1,"A01"),
            new(2,"B01"),
            new(3,null),
            new(4,""),
            new(5,"A02"),
            new(6,"A02"),
            new(7,"B02"),
            new(8,"B"),
            new(9,"D"),
        };

        var result = list.Where(x => x.Value == null || (!x.Value.StartsWith("B") && !x.Value.StartsWith("A")));
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```